# Generate a URL with http:// using URIBuilder

Tags: java, spring, apache, url

Using Apache's URIBuilder class.

Tried Generating URL with the following snippet:

```
URI uri = new URIBuilder("/purchaseurl/sample")
          .setScheme("http")              
          .addParameter("name","abc")
          .build();
```

The Result I expect is:
    http:///purchaseurl/sample?name=abc

But the Actual O/P is: 
    http:/purchaseurl/sample?name=abc

Is there any way to achieve my expected O/P?

Comment: So, you want a URI with no host name?

Comment: Your URI is not valid as it is missing the host part. That is why URIBuilder returns the URI in the above form.

Comment: I am using this is JUnit Test so I don't want the HostName. Just for asserting and testing.

Comment: According to the [URL Standard](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/), the host part is mandatory for a valid `http` URL.

Comment: Ok so the point is once you add host using setHost("hostname") you will get the entire URL as I expect with http://.